# Azure SDK ARM Template deployment: Could not find member 'id'

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-rm-template, azure-sdk

I'm trying to deploy a vm through the python azure sdk with an arm template. I'm using the code provided by microsoft from here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/resource-manager-python-template-deployment/resource-manager-python-template-deployment/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

But I get an error when trying to use the template.

```
parameters = my parameters as a python dict
       
parameters = {k: {'value': v} for k, v in parameters.items()}
template = self.ts_client.template_specs.get('test-rg', 'deploy-vm.test').as_dict()

deployment_properties = {'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
                       'template': template,
                       'parameters': parameters}
    
self.client.deployments.create_or_update(self.resource_group,'azure-sample', {'properties': deployment_properties, 'tags': []})
```

The only part thats different from the example code, is that I'm not reading the template from a file but I'm getting it through the sdk and converting it into a dictonary and I pass the deployment_properties into the begin_create_or_update method as a dict. If I don't pass it like this it gives the exception: Parameter 'Deployment.properties' can not be None.

However I get this error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidRequestContent) The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'id' on object of type 'Template'. Path 'properties.template.id', line 1, position 34.'.
```

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: The error message specifically highlights a missing property that is required. Have you verified that your template has that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got same type of error.**

**Console:**
[image]

Make sure you are passing correct Arm template **`template.json`** and also check it is in correct state.
Provide the valid id or correct the templates according to **Azure-VM** templates using this [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-template?toc=/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/toc.json).

After I validated my templates using document the virtual machine is deployed successfully using python with Arm templates.

**Code:**

```
from  azure.mgmt.resource  import  ResourceManagementClient
from  azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models  import  DeploymentMode
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential
import  json


subscription_id = '<subscription id>'
resource_group = '<your rg name >'
creds = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = ResourceManagementClient( creds, '<sub id>')

parameters = {
'virtualMachineName': '',
'location': '',
'virtualMachineRG':''
}

parameters = {k: {'value': v} for  k, v  in  parameters.items()}
with  open(r'<path of file >', 'r') as  template_file_fd:
template = json.load(template_file_fd)
deployment_properties = {
'mode': DeploymentMode.incremental,
'template': template,
'parameters': parameters
}
deployment_async_operation = client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
resource_group, 'azure-sample', {'properties': deployment_properties, 'tags': []})
deployment_async_operation.wait()
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template)

Comment: The problem was trying to use the template the way I did. ts_client.template_specs.get('test-rg', 'deploy-vmtest').as_dict() gives back a dictionary but it's not the full template just some meta information.